# How can I pick the lowest number from a list of numbers?

Tags: javascript, list, numbers

I have four numbers that can possible be the same, but or most likely different. Basically I want this function to chose no number of they are equal, but if they aren't, pick the lowest one, and if there are two that are the same, to just pick one of them and go with that.

Like for example I have `3434`, `3396`, `3414`, and `3374`. Well I want the function to return to me say `0` if they're all the same, `1` for the first one and so on. So in this situation I would need to be returned `4`.

But if the numbers were `321`, `576`, `812`, and `321` it would return to me `1`.

I've been at this for a couple of days now and I just can't seem to find any way of doing what I need to do. Anyone know something that could make this work magically? Thanks!

**EDIT**
My approach had me doing something along the lines of creating an array sorting it and trying to use the last result, but when I sort the array, the keys get messed up so I don't know which value it belonged to

```
 var choices = new Array();
 choices[1] = parseInt(value1);
 choices[2] = ...
 choices = choices.sort();
 //and then I ran into the problem that my keys being not starting 
 //with 0, it added an element which I was able to remove by doing this
 choices = choices.splice(0,4);
```

And then I'm stuck for there

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Someone may be able to see what you are missing easier than having to write the whole algorithm from scratch.

Comment: Arrays are zero-based. The first element is at `choices[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a start on the journey to answering your question. As others have pointed out, this code does not handle all the cases you mention; this is deliberate.

> How can I pick the lowest number from a list of numbers?

Hand-rolled way; `O(n)` and one pass:

```
var myList = [3434, 3396, 3414, 3374];
var min = Infinity;
var minIndex = -1;
var current;

for (var i=0; i<myList.length; i++)
{
    current = myList[i];
    if (current < min)
    {
        min = current;
        minIndex = i;
    }
}

// the value you want is in minIndex
```

Far more concise; also `O(n)` but two passes through the array:

```
var min = Math.min.apply(null, myList);
var minIndex = myList.indexOf(min);
```

**N.B** `Array.indexOf` requires a shim in older versions of IE.

---

> Basically I want this function to chose no number of they are equal

This exercise, as they say, is left to the reader.

Comment: Does not seem to return no number if all numbers are equal.

Comment: This returns a zero-based index.  He wants a one-based index.

Comment: @JohnKurlak I know. Is it really too much to ask the OP to do even the slightest amount of thinking?

Comment: @Thilo of course you're right. Does this really need to be spoon-fed to the OP from a silver platter?

Comment: `Basically I want this function to chose no number of they are equal` I'm not even sure why I added that, because that part works without error

Comment: Actually his answer helped me out entirely, making me realize that my original approach was completely off and this way makes a ton more sense, thanks a ton!